error during arch linux installation "usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71"

i am trying to install arch linux on my new thinkpad e15.
i have disabled secure boot and other security technologies.
would appreciate comments even if they do not solve my issue.
this is what i get after plugging in the stick into the port on the right hand side of the laptop (which i assume is a lower speed port)
the error is still there but the installer launches (kind of) but i cannot execute any commands and it keeps spamming that error on loop.

The issue was a faulty camera and mic module in the laptop.
After disconnecting the module or turning it off in the bios settings the issue no longer occurs, and the laptop functions normally.

That's a hardware problem; some USB device is misbehaving, on a very fundamental level.
The good news is that it doesn't seem to be the problem. The problem is that you have something that behaves like a microcontroller that is supposed to "speak" USB but which someone forgot to program. If you have external USB devices attached via questionable cables, USB novelty things (fans, coffee pot warmers…) or USB development boards, attached, this would be a good time to remove them.
The problem is that you have a FAT file system with a broken filesystem descriptor ("bogus number…"). And interestingly you're trying to access that – it might "just" be the EFI system partition (which seems to be still sufficiently functional – otherwise you wouldn't have booted this far).
What worries me more is that your UUID doesn't look like a valid UUID to me (not sure), but something manually chosen, and now not found.
So, honestly, there are multiple faulty things about this installation; you could try a more mature Linux installer (Arch having a proper installer is relatively new, and the arch user base is comparatively small compared to large distros. I have had pretty good experiences with the Fedora Linux installer. No need to keep using Fedora afterwards – just to help you figure out what's wrong) and see whether that works. In any case, booting from a stick, and running a FAT file system check on nvme0n1p2 before doing anything else would seem advisable.

i greatly appreciate your reply to my question. I have nothing but the 16gb usb flash usb connected, i flashed the stick using etcher with the most recent archlinux iso file from a uk mirror (allworldit.com). I will say that the stick did have opensuse tumbleweed before that but that didnt install aswell after being stuck at the driver screen with the green bar stuck at full, thats the reason im interested in arch as i want a rolling release to mess around with and learn about computers in the process, i have installed arch before on my desktop computer with no issues.

then it's likely that stick that resets on the bus. Try with some other stick.

ok i have just tried the stick on my desktop computer and it loads the installer perfectly, i have also plugged the stick into a lower speed usb port on the side of the laptop and it goes further than before but seems to be having errors during the systemd startup and even before it.

yeah dump that stick.

i have updated my question with the recent developments if you are interested. if not thank you for your help.

i used another stick and got the same error, could it be my usb ports problem?

might be? But unusual. Check for "loose" (mechanically) connection. Not being able to read the descriptor really means that the USB host side does everything, but the device side doesn't react.

alright used another stick on that right side usb port and the installer booted successfully and am now installing arch, thank you for your help. i wont mark this as answered because i still dont know what happened and it could happen another day

it is your USB hardware, as you can clearly see from the error message. So, there's really not anything else to blame here.

hello i have been using arch now for a while and it still pops up for example after i do the reboot command it gets halted by the error then ill have to force power off the computer, it isnt a big problem but its still there. is there anything you recommend i try?
